# Is the base of natural logarithms $e$ efficiently computable?

Tags: complexity-theory, theory

Is $e = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!} +\ldots$ efficiently computable? To be more specific, we say that a real number $r$ is efficiently computable if there is a polynomial time algorithm that takes a positive integer $C$ as input and outputs a rational number $y$ such that $r−\frac{1}{C}\leq y \leq r+\frac{1}{C}$.

If it is computable, what would the high-level algorithm be? Or how do we argue that it is not computable?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Take into account that, for $C\geq 2$, we have that $0\leq e-\left(1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\ldots+\frac{1}{C!}\right)=\frac{1}{(C+1)!}+\frac{1}{(C+2)!}+...\leq\frac{1}{C}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+...\right)=\frac{1}{C}$. The algorithm could input $C$ and output $y=1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\ldots+\frac{1}{C!}$.

Comment: @plop That wouldn't be polynomial time, though, since the input size is $\log C$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to check (for example using a [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) of $e^x$ at $x=0$) that for all $n \geq 0$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} < e < \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} + \frac{e}{(n+1)!} < \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} + \frac{3}{(n+1)!}.
$$
Moreover,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^n \prod_{i=k+1}^n i}{n!}.
$$
This formula gives an algorithm, running in time $\mathit{poly}(n)$, for computing $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}$. This quantity satisfies your requirements if $\frac{3}{(n+1)!} \leq \frac{1}{C}$, that is, if $(n+1)! \geq 3C$. Since $(n+1)! \geq 2^n$, it suffices to choose $n = O(\log C)$. This gives an algorithm running in time $\mathit{poly}(\log C)$. Since the length of the encoding of $C$ is $\Theta(\log C)$, the resulting algorithm runs in polynomial time.